# How can I change the file path of files referenced via the download role to not use a hashed folder?

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I want to provide a link to a file in my project, but I want this link to be human readable and perma-ish.

Doing this:

```
Link to file for reference :download:`myfile.json <../myproject/myfile.json>`.
```

Generates a link that looks like this:

```
...../myproject/docs/_build/html/_downloads/b4c73f3851c188db23a20daeed2c/myfile.json
```

Do I have control over this? I want the link to just be this:

```
...../myproject/docs/_build/html/_downloads/myfile.json
```

I would actually prefer the link be in the root so it's just:

```
...../myproject/myfile.json
```

Comment: Not at this time, out of the box. There is an open issue: https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/823

Comment: Does this mean every time I change the file the path with change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`download` role](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/roles.html#role-download) does what it says in the documentation, i.e., it creates links with a unique hash. I don't see a way around it unless the implementation is changed.

But

> I would actually prefer the link be in the root

In this particular case we can (ab)use [`html_extra_path`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#confval-html_extra_path), adding this in `conf.py`

```py
html_extra_path = ['../myproject/myfile.json']
```

and refer to the file with a regular [hyperlink](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/basics.html#external-links):

```
Link to file for reference `myfile.json <myfile.json>`_.
```

The file is then necessarily in the root folder (of the built HTML documentation), as that's what `html_extra_path` does. It cannot be put in a subfolder such as `_downloads`.